# How to import a file that uses `export =` syntax?

Tags: typescript

I wan to import a library that uses `export =` syntax:

```
// File MyClass.ts
export = class MyClass {
```

How co I import this file in my another file:

```
import MyClass from './MyClass.ts' // throws "MyClass has no default export"
```

Answer (score 0):

> import MyClass from './MyClass.ts' // throws "MyClass has no default export"

`export =` cannot be imported using the ES6 module pattern. This is because in ES6 each export must be more explicit.

## Fix

Import using

```
import MyClass = require('./MyClass');
```

## Better fix

Steer clear of `export =` and even `export default` (more on this https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/tips/defaultIsBad.html)